# Custom GIS Routes

Tags: java, anylogic

I have a list of GIS point that creates a route network.

My goal is to let agents move from a point to another using ONLY the network I provided. 
I don't want to use all the possible routes from a point A to a point B, just the ones that I can follow based on my own network.

I know that it should be possible by implementing a custom RouteProvider,  but I was not able to figure out how to do it.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a collection "locations" of type ArrayList containing all your GISPoints, here is what you do:

```
//create a new GIS network and attach it to your map element
GISNetwork network = new GISNetwork(map,"myNetwork");

//add all GISPoints to this network
for(GISPoint p:locations){
    network.add(p);
}

//somehow iterate through your points to create Routes between them (here just connect one after another, no cross connections)
for(int i=0;i<locations.size()-1;i++){

    //create segment (neccessary for Curve)
    GISMarkupSegment segment = new GISMarkupSegmentLine(locations.get(i).getLatitude(), locations.get(i).getLongitude(), locations.get(i+1).getLatitude(), locations.get(i+1).getLongitude());

    //create curves (neccessary for the GISRoutes)
    Curve<GISMarkupSegment> curve = new Curve<>();

    curve.addSegment(segment);  
    curve.initialize();
    network.add(new GISRoute(map,curve,locations.get(i), locations.get(i+1), true));
}
network.initialize();
```

Comment: Thank you very much.

I created the GIS Network. I will have more than one (sea, air, rail, ..).

How can I set a particoular Network to a population of agents?

Comment: You do not have to change the network, the network gets choosen automatically when the Agent is booked on a node belonging to this network at the time when the movement start. Note: One node can't be in more then one network in a time, so for interchanges you have to create a separate node per network at the same location. At this points where several networks meet, you have to manually make sure the transfers work, eg. use a moveTo with a "jump" in 0 time to switch between networks.

Comment: Amazing, you really saved me! Thanks Florian!

Comment: for changing the network we can also use the 'setNetwork()' function of the agents we want to follow that network.